# FlowDocumentPageViewer mouse scroll navigates to the next pages instead of scrolling to the end of the page first

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I am trying to show a PrintPreview in ActualSize Mode and I have the following structure in my xaml:






The problem is when I mouse scroll, instead of scrolling to the end of the page as you scroll and then navigate to the next page if any , it directly navigates to the next page and then on the last page, it scrolls to the end as you continue scrolling with your mouse.
Is there a way to overcome that problem without handling the ScrollChanged event of the ScrollViewer in the code behind ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to override the OnMouseWheel method of FlowDocumentPageViewer. Below is the original code:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Delta != 0)
    {
        if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                this.IncreaseZoom();
            }
            else
            {
                this.DecreaseZoom();
            }
        }
        else if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            base.PreviousPage();
        }
        else
        {
            base.NextPage();
        }
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    if (!e.Handled)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

In your code you must do as below:

```
public class MyPageViewer : FlowDocumentPageViewer
{
    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scroll_within_page_applicable())
        {
            scroll_within_page();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        }
    }
}
```